# how to remove blank spaces in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

[I want to remove those blank spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f81C0.png)
and is there any way to add data in the same row if it is null instead of adding in the next row

Comment: use `TRIM` function to remove leading and trailing spaces

Comment: use `update` statement for your second question.

Comment: Under what condition you want to insert new row?. And under what condition you want to update existing row?

Comment: It looks like you are using 1 insert statement per column?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use TRIM() function and replace() for /r/n

```
select replace(replace(trim(coloum_name),'/r',''),'/n','') from table;
```

and yes you can replace null with

```
select coalesce(coloum_with_null,'any_value') from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trim() function.

Example 1

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (TRIM('  value1 '),TRIM(' value2 '),TRIM(' value3 '),...);
```

Result:

'value1'....

Comment: no..i want to remove blank entries in databases. take a look at the picture

Comment: well i cant see the picture because of web filtering here, so i assumed that you want to remove a rows that is blank right? @Rahul

Comment: whenever i put data in my data base, it is inserted in only one column . the rest of the columns are inserted with null , when i add next time , the data goes into next row, instead i want it to go into the same row but different column

Comment: INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Stavanger', 'Norway');

Comment: UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the following query according to your table name and column name in order to remove the blank entries in your database.

```
DELETE FROM "table name" WHERE "column name" IS NULL;
```

and make use of the following query in order to update the already existing row

```
UPDATE "table name" SET "column name" = "any thing" WHERE "condition";
```

Comment: @Rahul can you describe what logic you are implementing in order to insert data ? and what actually you want to insert ? thanks